# How to use .NET class in Borland C++

Tags: c++, .net, dll, com, c++builder

There is a 3rd party SDK based on .NET technology which I want to use in Borland C++. What's the best way to use that SDK in Borland C++?

I was reading about "bridge", but it looks too complicated. I saw some questions/issues about COM callable DLL and Borland C++. Is COM callable DLL an option? Or, what about if I create a Web Service and expose those functions in SDK I need?

Thank you for your time!

Regards

Comment: If you were using the MS compiler, you could create a mixed mode assembly and export the classes that way. If you are prepared to expose the classes with a C style interface, you can still use a mixed mode assembly and `__declspec(dllexport)`. Otherwise, COM is a pretty sound option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We expose .NET components as COM objects to a legacy Borland C++ app (with [RegAsm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx)). Where we need a UI, we exposed [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx)-based WinForms controls as ActiveX controls. So far, this approach works OK.

Comment: I've been using the COM+ objects successfully but haven't managed to crack loading a UserControl into a form yet... Can you provide any sample code or hints?

Comment: @CJBrew, [Interop Forms Toolkit for C#](http://interoptoolkitcs.codeplex.com) should have everything you may need, including samples.